# jquery binding dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

I know how to bind click event for dynamically generated elements.

```
$("#abc").on("click", function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

But How can i bind the following examples.
For dynamically generated  ".tagManager" It doesn't work.

```
   $(".tagManager").tagsManager({
    prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
    preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
    typeahead: true,
    typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
    typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "New York", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
    blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
    blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
    hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
  });
```

Following clickover also doesnot  work for dynamically generated elements.

```
 $('[rel="clickover"]').clickover();
```

Comment: Using `.on()` the way you've shown only works for elements that already exist at the time you run that code - it will not automatically apply to elements added dynamically later. As far as running plugins against dynamically generated elements, can you not call the plugin from the same code that generates the elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)